# horizontal centering divs in a div 100% (wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, html

I'm trying to center horizontally a divs in a div with 100% width. The div conteiner  is "#post-area"  and all divs inside, have a class ".post".

this is the link: http://bit.ly/VOqkhv

When resize the browser is possible to see that not work good, in fact, all divs are not centering with the menu. How can fid this? I tried also with margin: auto; but nothing .

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set the 100% div to `position:relative` then the element you want to center to `position:relative; margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: Thank you bennett_an for your reply! With the float:left desactivated and the other css option now work good!

Answer (score 0):

That is because they are floating to the left. You can use inline-block instead.

Add `text-align: center;` to #post-area

Remove `float: left;` and add `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; text-align:left;` to .type-post